# Can't convert files using winff: Error opening filters!

Tags: winff

I give an mkv format movie for conversion but it shows like these :

```
[buffer @ 0x118fa40] Invalid pixel format string '-1' ; Error opening filters!
```

What should I do?

Comment: What program are you using for the conversion?

Answer (score 0):

Your ffmpeg filters have problem, just reinstall it, that should solve problem

```
sudo apt-get autoremove --purge ffmpeg
sudo apt-get install ffmpeg
```

You might also need to install winff after this,

```
sudo apt-get install winff
```

Try converting after this it should work, if it doesn't then you might be trying to use a filter that has a dependency unfulfilled. Try converting directly from terminal and tell if you encounter same error,

```
ffmpeg -i videoFile.mkv -vcodec copy -acodec copy VideoFile.mp4
```